# Is Minecraft Story Mode a multiplayer game?

Tags: minecraft-story-mode

This question is pretty self explanatory. Is Minecraft Story Mode a multiplayer game?

I thought it was multiplayer because I've been told by multiple people that it is,   but when I did some research on it, I couldn't find anything about whether it is multiplayer or not. Is this game multiplayer or is it only single player?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Minecraft story mode](http://store.steampowered.com/app/376870/) is a singleplayer game.

[The Telltale games](https://www.telltalegames.com/) are [point-and-click graphic adventure video games](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minecraft:_Story_Mode). They are all singleplayer experiences that tell a story according to the choices you make.

Answer (score 0):

It's a single player game with other computer-controlled characters. You play with no one but yourself.